# EC2 Instance install x11 libraries

Tags: amazon-ec2, x11, putty

I have a java app running on ec2 instance and I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or  directory
```

I know this error is because I am missing the x11 libraries. Can someone please help me install this missing libraries? I am logged into the ec2 instance via putty.

Thank you for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following lines from putty and that did it.

```
sudo yum install libXt.{i686,x86_64}
```

Then I got another error for missing libXmu.so.6.

```
sudo yum install libXmu.{i686,x86_64}
```

and that solved it.